# How to prevent sprite from rotation inside Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to prevent sprite from rotation inside Corona ?
When I set

```
-- Create a new sprite and add it to the group
local spriteInstance = display.newSprite( imagesheet, spriteSequences.cat )
spriteInstance.x = 100
spriteInstance.y = 100
spriteInstance.isFixedRotation  = true
```

it is ignored but when I inside touch function do like

```
function touch(event)

    event.target.isFixedRotation = true
end
```

after touch it works. Does anyone know what is a problem ?

Comment: clarify "it is ignored" and "it works": what makes you say it is ignored, what makes you say it works

Answer (score 2):

Add `physics` to the body first, then assign `isFixedRotation` to it. Like:

```
--Add a body to the rectangle
physics.addBody( spriteInstance, "dynamic" )

-- Assign your property
myRect.isFixedRotation = true
```

Here you are assigning `isFixedRotation = true` during the `touch` event. So, remove that code within your touch function and add it just after creating the physics body as:

```
spriteInstance.isFixedRotation = true
```

Keep Coding............. :)